# how to maintain session with phonegap for windows phone 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8

I m working with **phonegap** for **windows phone 8**.I want to maintain **session** using ajax.I am not using any **php** script for this.Is it possible to maintain session with ajax  only and if possible then please provide me some sample code .

Comment: if you're using ajax, then you got to have some server backend. How do you perform log in without any (php) script?

Comment: i m not using any php here..i m working with visual express 2012 n there is no extension tool for php..